# Oracle Proxy Authentication in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, jdbc, jruby

Using the `oracle_enhanced` adapter and `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`, how can we utilize the proxy authentication described in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/proxya.htm#CHDHHAAD)? Specifically, how can we mimic this code from Java in Ruby:

```
java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
prop.put(OracleConnection.PROXY_USER_NAME, "jeff");
String[] roles = {"role1", "role2"};
prop.put(OracleConnection.PROXY_ROLES, roles);
conn.openProxySession(OracleConnection.PROXYTYPE_USER_NAME, prop);
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be built-in support in oracle_enhanced adapter at this point. There may be another way to accomplish that.

Comment: Any insight on how to do it? Like maybe using Java code in Ruby?